# Parsing JSON on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this code to parse JSON on JQUERY

```
var json_text2 = $.parseJSON('{"data":[["1340650436","2.00000"],["1340736844","4.00000"]],"label":"Waist Size (cm)"},{"data":[["1340736861","3.40000"],["1340650514","4.00000"]],"label":"Arm Size (Inch)","yaxis":"2"}');
```

BUT I got this error on Firebug

```
JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

Comment: Your object looks like `{...},{...}`. That's invalid JSON. You probably want `[{..},{..}]`.

Comment: that looks like an answer to me?

Comment: try running it through [json lint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A valid JSON string needs to be a single object or an array of objects. Wrap your objects in array brackets `[]`:

```
var json_text2 = $.parseJSON('[{"data":[["1340650436","2.00000"],["1340736844","4.00000"]],"label":"Waist Size (cm)"},{"data":[["1340736861","3.40000"],["1340650514","4.00000"]],"label":"Arm Size (Inch)","yaxis":"2"}]');
```

Comment: Or a string actually or array of strings as well. :)

Comment: Tested that JSON on http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm. Its still saying invalid JSON.

Comment: @Dev, it checks out on jsFiddle on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/ZBad9/. Works fine on your link too. Did you include the outer single quotes, because that's not part of the actual JSON string

Comment: Thanks YOU! solved the problem now! :) I was having on my code [json_text2] now I just removed the  '[' and ']' and place it on the parseJSON :) Thanks a lot!!!